# Stopping .click() listener until fadeIn() is finished in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface

```
$('#div1_button').click(function() {

    $('#div0').fadeOut(function(){          
        $('#div1').fadeIn();    
    });

});
```

When a user clicks div1_button the previously selected div0 fades out and div1 fades in. If the user goes click crazy and clicks div2 before div1 is finished fading in then div2 begins to fade in and eventually div1 fades out, but they stack on top of each other until div1 is finished fading in then fades out. How can I stop the .click() event until the clicked div is finished fading in.

Comment: So many good answers I actually ended up going with the .stop() because I feel it would be better to have the user get what they request instead of having to wait for the animation to finish and then request again. I know it wasn't what I asked for, but thanks to everyone who replied!

Comment: Thanks, thats actually a good pick considering user experience :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can stop animations by using the jQuery .stop() function.
http://api.jquery.com/stop/

```
$('#div1_button').click(function() {

    $('#div0').stop(true, true).fadeOut(function(){          
        $('#div1').stop(true, true).fadeIn();    
    });

});
```

While this is not exactly what you requested, it's definitely what I would've done.

Comment: wouldn't waiting for the animation to complete be a much better idea ?

Answer (score 4):

Something like

```
var div1_bclick_inprogress = false;
$('#div1_button').click(function() {
    if (!div1_bclick_inprogress) {
        div1_bclick_inprogress = true;
        $('#div0').fadeOut(function(){          
            $('#div1').fadeIn(function(){
                 div1_bclick_inprogress = false;
            });    
        });
    }

});
```

but you may have to experiment a bit with the details

Comment: there is no need to make / set / reset flags, jquery provides internal flag call :animated .. using it would be much cleaner and it serves the same purpose :)

Comment: alright :) I have never used jQuery so I don't know the details. I use Prototype and Ext.

Comment: Oh ok .. :) Here is the link for reference and further reading: http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/

Comment: I'll read the documentation if I ever need to use it :) right now I just wanted to give him the obvious answer (if you have spent some time with js) that works even though it wasn't "the jQuery way".

Answer (score 3):

USE :animated .. 
http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/

Here: an example

```
$("#div1_button").click(function() {
    if (!$(this).parent().children().is(':animated')) {
            $('#div0').fadeOut(function(){          
                $('#div1').fadeIn();    
          });
    }
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

don't you think that is better to stop the fadeIn/fadeOut and change the direction as the user requested?

in this case:

```
$('#div1_button').click(function() {
    var state = $(this).data("state");
    $(this).data(state, !state);

    var d0 = $("#div0").stop(),
        d1 = $("#div1").stop();

    if (state) {
      d0.fadeOut(function() {          
        d1.fadeIn();    
      });
    } else {
      d0.fadeIn(function() {
        d1.fadeOut();
      });
    }
});
```

or something like this

Answer (score 1):

```
div1_click_handler = function()
{
    $('#div1_button').unbind('click', div1_click_handler);

    $('#div0').fadeOut('slow', function()
    {
        $('#div1').fadeIn('slow', function()
        {
            $('#div1_button').click(div1_click_handler);                
        });
    });
});

$('#div1_button').click(div1_click_handler);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create an external boolean value that each click value checks before fading. i.e.

```
var noFading = true;
$('#div1_button').click(function() {
    if (noFading) {
        noFading = false;
        $('#div0').fadeOut(function(){          
            $('#div1').fadeIn(function() { noFading = true; });    
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [jQuery.data](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to store a flag. Set the flag after the first click, and ignore clicks until the flag is unset by the fade finishing:

```
$('#div1_button').click(function() {
    if ($('#div1').data('disableClick') === true) return false;

    $('#div1').data('disableClick', true);

    $('#div0').fadeOut(function(){          
        $('#div1').fadeIn(function() {
            $('#div1').data('disableClick', false);
        });    
    });
});
```